# Local thresholding of an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

Hi I have an image which is generated using `imagesc(img)`. The image contains the values ranging from 0 to 18. I want to apply thresholding in matlab in such a way that

```
for 0<img<5----> no change
for 6<img<8----> increase pixel value by 15
for 10<img<12---> increase by 10
for 12<img<15--> increase by 8
for 15<img<18---> increase by 6
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to index your img variable by your conditions:

```
img(img > 15 & img < 18) = img(img > 15 & img < 18) + 6;
img(img > 12 & img < 15) = img(img > 12 & img < 15) + 8;
img(img > 10 & img < 12) = img(img > 10 & img < 12) + 10;
img(img > 6 & img < 8) = img(img > 6 & img < 8) + 15;
```